# how to center the table and text in HTML

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I'm a beginner in coding and this is my code. It has a table with a TextBox and text in it, I just want help with how to put the whole form in the center of the page when I run my project

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <table class="auto-style1">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Insert Username and 
Password<br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; to load your the interface with<br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; log on application<br /><br />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="auto-style2">UserName<br />
      </td>
      <td>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txt_username" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="auto-style2">Password</td>
      <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br /><br />
```

Comment: Have you set align='center' style for your table?

Comment: no i tried couple of ways but didn't work fine i just want what should be added to my code

Comment: @SelvaTS align=center is deprecated in HTML5. CSS should be used.  See https://html.com/attributes/table-align/ or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

Comment: this is a HTML and CSS question, the use of asp.net has no bearing on the solution. It's also likely to be a duplicate of many previous questions. Did you do any research?

Comment: i know its html but i am using visual studio c# and doing a web app

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for the update.

Comment: @realprogramming "i know its html but i am using visual studio c# and doing a web app"..that's beside the point. You're asking about displaying things in a certain way... in any web app (regardless if it's asp.net or php or Node on the server-side), display and formatting is controlled by the HTML and CSS. I tagged it better so more people with relevant skills would see the question in their feed. But again, what did you research or try? This kind of thing is a very common question. Did you google your requirement?

Comment: can you show your desired output

Comment: or how your table should look like

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Other answers suggest to use css, I will tell an only HTML way,
Use `<center>` tag, like this-

```html
<body>
  <center>
    Centered text &hellip; <!-- Your html code here -->
  </center>
</body>
```

Your all elements and text within the center tag, would be aligned in the center.

Comment: The `<center>` tag is not supported in HTML5. It works but using CSS would be much better.

Answer (score 0):

I have added a snippet to align a table in the middle and center off your page.

```css
.items {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
.items .item {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <table class="item">
     <tr>
       <td>Some table</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the form to appear in the center of the screen, I would recommend using flexbox.
I added a container around your form and placed it in the center using `align-items` (vertical) and `justify-content` (horizontal).

Should you want to learn more about flexbox, you can find it [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <table class="auto-style1">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Insert Username and Password
          <br /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; to load your the interface with<br /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; log on application<br /><br />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="auto-style2">UserName<br />
        </td>
        <td>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txt_username" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="auto-style2">Password</td>
        <td>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txt_password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br /><br />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this

```css
#wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: auto;
    }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
(Your form here)
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use visual effects, u must learn css, it's easy and useful for desing.
Basicly;

```css
/*You can a width for form element, Because form attribute is block element that is feel it's area on page */
/*I cused 500px for example and than i used CSS margin property with "0 auto" values that is centered on page */

#form1 {
  border: 1px solid grey; /*Only you can see form element located area*/
  width:500px; 
  margin: 0 auto; /*Centered*/
}

/*Advice: dont use &nbsp; or <br>. You can use padding or margin on CSS*/
#form1 td[colspan] {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
/*Insert style tag on your page and pull in this document*/
```

```html
<!-- Insert Code via <style>CSS Code Here</style> -->

<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">Insert Username and Password<br /> to load your the interface with
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="auto-style2">UserName<br />
      </td>
      <td>
        <!--asp:TextBox ID="txt_username" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br /-->
        <input type="text" name="username">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <td class="auto-style2">Password</td>
    <td>
      <!--asp:TextBox ID="txt_password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox-->
      <input type="text" name="password">
    </td>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the height of the div to how much you needed

```html
<div style="position:absolute;width:50%;height:50%;top:0;bottom:0;right:0;left:0;margin:auto;">
<form>
<table class="auto-style1" border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4"> Insert Username and 
Password to load your the interface with
 log on application
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="50%" colspan="2">UserName
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
         your content
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
      <td width="50%" colspan="2">Password</td>
      <td>
      your content
      </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </div>
```